# swagger Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')

Tags: http, https, swagger

I had a Web-Api ASP.NET Core 8 project configured to work over https. Later I needed to run it on IIS via http.
I removed

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection()
```

and tried different manipulations in the launchSettings.json file
However, every time I try to run swagger in the browser console I see Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith'). However, swagger itself does not start.
How can I reconfigure swagger to work via http? Or what
there may be a reason for the specified message being output to the console?